# Laravel HasManyThrough Relation with BelongsTo

Tags: laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

i have a model `User` that has BelongsTo relation with `Accounts`
And `Accounts` model HasMany relation with `Journals`
I want to have relation with `User` and `Journal`

I have tried HasManyThrough but i think it should work if i have `User` HasMany relation with `Accounts` and `Accounts` should HasMany relation with `Journal`

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

-> I think you need to create pivot table for creating many-to-many relationship between User and Journal. i think this example is useful for you.

```
CREATE
 
TABLE user_journals (
  user_id INT
 
NOT
 
NULL,
  journal_id INT
 
NOT
 
NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, journal_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (journal_id) REFERENCES journals (id)
);
```

**Add snippet in User.php Model like below**

```
public function journals()
     return $this->belongsToMany(Journal::class, 'user_journals');
```

**or in Journal.php Model like below**

```
public function users()
     return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_journals');
```

-> I think after created the pivot table and updated your models, you can start using the relationship. For example

```
$user = User::find(1);
$journals = $user->journals;

$journal = Journal::find(1);
$users = $journal->users;
```

-> I hope this is helpful for you.